# How to merge the corr.test result ( correlaiton only or P value only) to a table

Tags: r, correlation

Recently I wanna output all my corr.test result (corrlation) to a table.

Because I have a huge data with 30 thousand genes .

It costs me much time calculating the correlation between genes .

And if I use lapply and output them as list in R environment it will take up a lot of memory.

So I wanna  output them but in only a table just like merging them togather in the end of a lapply loop.
Though it will cost much time, it will save a lot of memory.

However I'm not familiar to apply function. I don't know how to merge the (correlation or p value)results all.

I need your help.

Here is my sample data and code:

```
data_logg<-structure(c(6.05572382866802, 11.1380021588504, 9.3044407551291, 
7.87123980178745, 10.1452025129037, 8.93954331139168, 7.72897302870656, 
8.31753461010792, 6.91902649139208, 8.81063297295094, 22.5569750353369, 
31.520979452157, 28.3261317078564, 25.402957920785, 35.8148569235307, 
27.8723220522029, 41.0335341398849, 28.5846501726903, 21.398001509988, 
33.063696558847, 15.182913110301, 14.6438943008441, 16.1624032499377, 
13.1264245066984, 13.4072656803608, 14.7364553246895, 13.1211732101273, 
14.3003714459557, 14.918175412959, 15.7912093225492, 0.0931714621767618, 
0.0303852980725358, 0.0114778232990823, 0.0260809645231031, 0, 
0.0310539968593767, 0.019047166325137, 0.0105050244811974, 0.0264828042698263, 
0.0346757324524723, 3.46286706915552, 4.99156437489882, 5.70180521646014, 
4.0868441874337, 4.51377652615602, 5.35554484236395, 5.44397291505049, 
6.57811217176637, 5.10097757787774, 5.18489532380933, 1.12546006270081, 
1.91823256736007, 1.8500381393557, 1.4401998592, 1.14712309386819, 
1.63756861783462, 1.63809356500207, 1.99896249233356, 1.3388769544766, 
2.07437306868356, 1.5068638533804, 2.63183788279904, 3.12822707867838, 
2.44752756389731, 2.37001697139819, 2.51118444838866, 3.48267851492631, 
3.26267014874084, 1.75288566197561, 2.80059464803222, 21.3209507790769, 
22.6744418461091, 16.9622647095367, 22.2902884855603, 25.7854403101755, 
20.6976499521803, 24.1019869113154, 24.764924561036, 22.8547950562338, 
15.9953039663019), .Dim = c(10L, 8L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, 
    c("Zzef1", "Zyx", "Zyg11b", "Zyg11a", "Zxdc", "Zxdb", "Zxda", 
    "Zwint")))

Correlation_list<-lapply(colnames(data),function(ii){
  
  i<-match(ii,colnames(data))
  #  i<-ii %in% colnames(data_logg)
  tm <- corr.test(data[,i,drop=FALSE],
                  y = data[,-i], use = "pairwise", "spearman", adjust="none", 
                  alpha=0.05, ci=F, minlength=5)
  
  res<-t(tm["r"])
  colnames(res)<-paste0(ii,"_Correlaiton")
  na.omit(res)
  data_merege<-merge(res,)  ##  ? Here I don't know how to do it.
})
```

**How to do next with : data_merege<-merge(res,)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: 2021-03-26 09:20:55.

Sorry, I get the right answer by myself.
I'm so stupid that it can be done using corr.test.

And it worried me day and night.

My answer:

```
tm <- corr.test(data_cor,
                y = data_cor, use = "pairwise", "spearman", adjust="none", 
                alpha=0.05, ci=F, minlength=5)
tm$r
tm$p
```

Just change the x input as the total data too.

It mean calculate the correlation with itself totally.